# Not able to access the FLEX ,BLAZEDS,JAVA Application from other computer

Tags: apache-flex

I have developed a FLEX ,BLAZE DS,JAVA,Hibernate Application and able to deploy and run in my localhost on tomcat.

When i am trying to run the same URL with my IP Address from other computer in LAN. I am able to see the FLEX page but when i clicking on "Login" button,nothing is happening, means it is not further communicating to server and always looking for localhost.

I am pasting the some part of service-config and hibernate-cfg.xml contents for ref.
service-config.xml

```
<channel-definition id="my-amf" class="mx.messaging.channels.AMFChannel">
        <endpoint url="http://{server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/messagebroker/amf" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint"/>
    </channel-definition>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://{server.name}/testdb</property>
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.
Aj

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a security issue.
On the computer that doesn't work, make sure you add the application's domain or folder into the Flash Global Security list:
http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html

For example, if you're accessing from an IP 192.168.0.0, add http://192.168.0.0 into the list.

If this doesn't work, make sure you narrow down the problem by using Firebug on Firefox, or similar tool to see if there are any errors in the network calls (data may be getting an error message, etc).

If you find that your error is transferring, and the bug is in your application- get FlashTracer and the Flash Debug Player so that you can trace any Flex/Flash errors that occur. I'm naming some of the tools I'm using, but I'm sure there are other debugging tools out there that can help you do the same thing.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Garrt, looks like a security issue. I know that you may have some problems when you try to access the server from a differente domain. In this link they explain some configurations that should be done:
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-01-2009/jw-01-javaee-flex-1.html?page=5

I hope it helps!